# Drawing a rectangle on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a simple canvas program where the user can consistently create new shapes. This one is just a basic rectangle creator (I am hoping to expand it more to circles, lines, and maybe even other stuff). Right now though I have created something that is working in a really weird way.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta chartset="utf-8">
    <title>Dragging a square</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas, context, startX, endX, startY, endY;
        var mouseIsDown = 0;

        function init() {
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseXY, false);

            document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
        }

        function mouseUp() {
            mouseIsDown = 0;
            //mouseXY();
        }

        function mouseDown() {
            mouseIsDown = 1;
            startX = event.clientX;
            startY = event.clientY;
            mouseXY();
        }

        function mouseXY(eve) {
            if (!eve) {
                var eve = event;
            }
            endX = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            endY = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

            drawSquare();
        }

        function drawSquare() {
            // creating a square
            var width = Math.abs(startX - endX);
            var height = Math.abs(startY - endY);

            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(startX, startY, width, height);
            context.fillStyle = "yellow";
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 7;
            context.strokeStyle = 'black';
            context.stroke();

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer;"></canvas>
</body>
    </html>
```

Sorry about the slightly weird formatting when I copy and pasted my code. I think the problem is my mouseXY function. What I want is the user to click somewhere on the canvas a drag the mouse to create a rectangle, when the user lets go that is the end of that operation and they can create a whole new rectangle right after. At this point the program kind of just lets me click and create a new rectangle but if I let go of the mouse button it doesn't stop, in fact I have to click again to make it stop which then creates a new rectangle. I am still very new to this and I am having a lot of trouble with this, I will continue to work on this and if I figure it out I will let the site know. Thank you and have a great day!

---

Well I got this to work (thanks to @Ken) but now I am trying to solve a new problem. I want to be able to put multiple rectangles on the canvas. I created a function that represents the Rectangle and then created a draw function within the rectangle function to draw out a rectangle. I created a new function called addShape() that ideally creates the rectangle object and pushes into an array called  square and drawShapes() that is supposed to erase everything on the canvas and redraws everything. Here is what I have so far:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta chartset="utf-8">
    <title>Dragging a square</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Rectangle(canvas, x, y, width, height,color) {
            //this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.color = color;

            this.draw = function() {

                this.context.globalAlpha = 0.85;
                this.context.beginPath();
                this.context.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
                this.context.strokeStyle = "black";
                this.context.lineWidth = 1;

                this.context.fill();
                this.context.stroke();
            };

        };

        // hold the canvas and context variable, as well as the 
        // starting point of X and Y and the end ones
        var canvas, context, startX, endX, startY, endY;
        var mouseIsDown = 0;

        // An array that holds all the squares
        var squares = [];

        window.onload = function() {
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseXY, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
        }

        function mouseUp(eve) {
            if (mouseIsDown !== 0) {
                mouseIsDown = 0;
                var pos = getMousePos(canvas, eve);
                endX = pos.x;
                endY = pos.y;

                //Square(); //update on mouse-up
                addShape(); // Update on mouse-up
            }
        }

        function mouseDown(eve) {
            mouseIsDown = 1;
            var pos = getMousePos(canvas, eve);
            startX = endX = pos.x;
            startY = endY = pos.y;
            // Square(); //update
            addShape();
        }

        function mouseXY(eve) {

            if (mouseIsDown !== 0) {
                var pos = getMousePos(canvas, eve);
                endX = pos.x;
                endY = pos.y;

                //Square();
                addShape();
            }
        }

        function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
                y: evt.clientY - rect.top
            };
        }

        function addShape() {
            var w = endX - startX;
            var h = endY - startY;
            var offsetX = (w < 0) ? w : 0;
            var offsetY = (h < 0) ? h : 0;
            var width = Math.abs(w);
            var height = Math.abs(h);

            var s = new Rectangle(startX + offsetX, startY + offsetY, width, height, "yellow");

            squares.push(s);

            // Update the display
            drawShapes();
        }

        function drawShapes() {
            context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

            for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
                var shape = squares[i];
                shape.draw();
            };
        }

        function clearCanvas() {
            squares = [];

            drawShapes();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="addShape()">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer;"></canvas><br>
    <button onclick="clearCanvas()">Clear Canvas</button>
</body>
    </html>
```

I am pretty sure I broke the original code... thank you for any help!

Comment: What happens if you change the mouseup event listener to the canvas like the other two?

Comment: The issue is that you're not utilizing information gathered by `mouseIsDown`

Comment: You mean I am not properly using it as a flag? Should I use it as a condition to move perhaps... okay I am going to try something.

Comment: Okay I added a condition in mouseXY that if mouseIsDown == 1 then start drawing. The problem now is that if I create a rectangle and then try to make it small it keeps drawing in itself, here is a the JSfiddle just so you can see what it is doing http://jsfiddle.net/8nA2x/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to modify a couple of things in the code: (edit: there are many issues with this code. I went through some of them inline here, but haven't tested. If you put it in a fiddle it's easier for us to check)..

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/fhr2wrw7/)**

When mouse down occur initialize both start and end points. Call a common draw function that is not dependent on the event itself:

```
function mouseDown(eve) {
    mouseIsDown = 1;
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, eve);
    startX = endX = pos.x;
    startY = endY = pos.y;
    drawSquare(); //update
}
```

At mouse up, only register if isMouseDown is true, else this function will handle all incoming up-events (as you have attatched it to document, which is correct - window could have been used too):

```
function mouseUp(eve) {
    if (mouseIsDown !== 0) {
        mouseIsDown = 0;
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, eve);
        endX = pos.x;
        endY = pos.y;
        drawSquare(); //update on mouse-up
    }
}
```

Only draw if mouseisdown is true:

```
function mouseXY(eve) {

    if (mouseIsDown !== 0) {
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, eve);
        endX = pos.x;
        endY = pos.y;

        drawSquare();
    }
}
```

In addition you will need to clear the previous area of the rectangle before drawing a new or else it won't show when you draw a bigger rectangle and then move the mouse back to draw a smaller one.

For simplicity you can do:

```
function drawSquare() {
    // creating a square
    var width = Math.abs(startX - endX);
    var height = Math.abs(startY - endY);

    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.width, context.height);
    //or use fillRect if you use a bg color

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(startX, startY, width, height);
    context.fillStyle = "yellow";
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 7;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();
}
```

Use this for mouse position:

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}
```

Comment: Umm this actually doesn't fix this. Try dragging the square a certain size and then dragging it back to make it smaller, it keep dragging leaving an ugly blotch. I want to be able to resize it without leaving that.

Comment: @InsigMath one more issue you need to deal with is negative width/height rectangles (you move start -width etc.). (I fixed this too - see fiddle again).

Comment: Thank you very much. But... and I'm sure this isn't a hard fix, but I would very much like to draw more than one rectangle. So, if I draw one, I want to be able to draw a whole another one over it. But, this is a great start :) thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry about the million questions and everything ... this has been a slightly frustrating learning experience

Comment: @InsigMath You will need to record the rectangles as object and redraw each time. In case the canvas is reset (window resize etc.) you will loose the content in any case if you don't do this.

Comment: Ahh okay, so I probably should create an array and just keep pushing them then.

Comment: I have some examples of this so I think I am fine from here. Thank you for all your help @Ken!!

Comment: @Ken... I think I need your expertise on this again. I want to be able to create multiple squares on the canvas. So I created a rectangle object like you suggested and I am trying to put them in an array and have it redrawn every time I draw a new square.... It isn't working at all. It's complaining a lot about canvas
this.context = canvas.getContext("2d"); under the Rectangle function which is why I have it blanked out. But in any case I just don't know how to do this. Maybe I have way over-complicated this

Comment: @InsigMath Sure, but open it as a new question as it is out of scope for this one. The error is because the the script is executed before the canvas is ready. Put the script at the end of body or execute it on the window's onload event. That will fix it.

Comment: @K3N any idea how to make the rectangle not vanish if one adds another?