# Adding a down menu to change shape of brush in Canvas Paint Program?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I’m trying to use a drop down menu to change the shape of a brush from round to square in a paint program using Canvas.

Here is what I have so far in this Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ohdust/k7wzj3ww/2/

```
  var tool = false;
var toolDefault = 'rect';

var toolSelect = document.getElementById('dtool');
```

I'm not sure how to go at this. Any examples would be helpful.

I've tried searching around but have not had any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function for each pencil types, for example:

```
function setRound() {
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.lineJoin = "round";
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#2b39c0';
}

function setSquare() {
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.lineCap = 'butt';
  ctx.lineJoin = "miter";
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#c0392b';
}
```

You would also have to remove setting the stroke style from the mouse handlers (see fiddle for additions to the resize handler as well as the `currentTool` declaration used below).

(if you have many different styles I would suggest considering at least an array and custom pen objects).

Then use a switch selector when an event on the tool selector is triggered:

```
toolSelect.addEventListener('change', setPencil);
...

function setPencil() {
  switch(this.value) {
    case "rect": 
        currentTool = setSquare; break;
    case "pencil": 
        currentTool = setRound; break;
  }
  currentTool();
}
```

Now the pencil will be updated according to the selected pencil in the menu.

Additionally, mouse position needs to be corrected - just add this to adjust:

```
function setPosition(e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  pos.x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  pos.y = e.clientY - rect.top;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7wzj3ww/4/)**

I have a small feeling you maybe ask for how to draw a rectangle and not a squared tip line. If so, check out **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226133/drawing-a-rectangle-on-canvas/17226305#17226305)**.

Comment: @markE "Useful answer ... BTW, your updated fiddle has gone 404-wonky. :-)" yeah, jsfiddle has had some problems these days. Not so much fun when you save and it ends with a 404.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the `onchange` attribute to run a function to change the type of brush. There is no rectangle shape for a brush as of now. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineCap).

**Note:** Other improvements need to be done in your code. For example the drawing is occurring far away from the cursor. And on click and move the browser is trying to drag things by default. So I guess you have to add a `mousemove` function to the canvas with `event.preventDefault()`.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var toolSelect = document.getElementById('dtool');


var brush = {};
brush.shape = 'round';
brush.size = 1;

function setBrush(type) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'pencil':
      brush.shape = 'round';
      brush.size = 1;
      break;
    case 'square':
      brush.shape = 'square';
      brush.size = 10;
      break;
  }
}


// some hotfixes... ( ≖_≖)
document.body.style.margin = 0;
canvas.style.position = 'fixed';

// get canvas 2D context and set him correct size
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
resize();

// last known position
var pos = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);

// new position from mouse event
function setPosition(e) {
  pos.x = e.clientX;
  pos.y = e.clientY;
}



// resize canvas
function resize() {
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function draw(e) {
  // mouse left button must be pressed
  if (e.buttons !== 1) return;

  ctx.beginPath(); // begin

  ctx.lineWidth = brush.size;
  ctx.lineCap = brush.shape;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#c0392b';

  ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y); // from
  setPosition(e);
  ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y); // to

  ctx.stroke(); // draw it!
}
```

```html
<label>Drawing tool:
  <select id="dtool" onchange="setBrush(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="square">Square</option>
    <option value="pencil">Pencil</option>
  </select>
</label>
```